# Fabric get( ) permission denied with use_sudo=True

Tags: python, fabric

With the fabric function:

```
def get_test():
    get("/home/wagans/test.txt", "/wagans/test.txt", use_sudo=True)
```

I'm getting a 'Permission denied' error.

Full error:

```
Fatal error: get() encountered an exception while downloading '/home/wagans/test.txt'

Underlying exception:
    Permission denied

Aborting.
Disconnecting from root@#########... done.
get() encountered an exception while downloading '/home/wagans/test.txt'

Underlying exception:
    Permission denied
```

I was connecting as a specific user, but tried connecting as root and still received the same result.

Output of "ls -l" on the remote_path are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  www-data   10 May  4 13:21 test.txt
```

Output for local path folder is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 user     306  3 May 17:56 wagans
```

The remote machine is Ubuntu 14.04, and local is OSX with fabric running in a virtualenv.

Can anyone help guide me to a solution?
Many thanks.

Comment: Does sudo require password input? If so, are you able to enter it somewhere? Else, it might be that your program fails to use sudo properly.

Comment: It doesn't prompt for password entry. I should note that removing use_sudo=True results in the same error.

Comment: But are password entries required to run sudo at all? Check your settings with the 'visudo' command.

Comment: check the user is in sudo list?

Comment: Did you launch your script with sudo?

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Spirine, I simply needed to launch the script with sudo. If you'd like to put that as the answer I'll mark as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly trying to use the rights of sudo in a script launched from your simple-user-rights. So, you must launch the script using the sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar error and found the solution:

```
"yourfile.py" [New File]
Fatal error: get() encountered an exception while 
downloading '/home/youruser/foobar'

Underlying exception:
    Operation not supported

Aborting.
```

The solution was not to store files in my home directory which has restricted permissions, you have to store and retrieve files in a open permissions directory like /tmp

Here is the code that works:

```
from fabric.operations import get

def fabric_ssh(ip_address, user, password, key_path, verbose=True):
    return settings(
                       host_string=ip_address,
                       user=user,
                       key_filename=key_path,
                       parallel=False,
                       warn_only=False)


with fabric_ssh("10.0.0.3", "your_user",
        "Yourpassword",
        "yourkeypath",
        True):

    get("foobar","/tmp/")
```

Finally it prints a success message after downling:

```
[10.130.28.191] download: /tmp/foobar <- /home/youruser/foobar
```